# arrow down link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

Ok, I'm not seeing something I guess...

I have an button that links down:

HTML:

```
<button id="get-down"><img src="images/arrow-down.png" /></button>
```

CSS:

```
#intro #get-down{
        min-width: 4%;
        max-width: 4%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -998;
        bottom: 2%;
        left: 46%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        #intro #get-down > img{
            border: none;
        }
```

JS:

```
// Scroll to demo section
$(function(toDemos) {
    $('#get-down').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo('#content', 500);
    });
});
```

The JS code worked before, when I put it on list elements. But this should be able to work as well right? Or am I missing something?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Do all of your elements have the same id? Are all of these list elements the same? If so, use a class instead.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it Ariel Flesler scrollTo?

Comment: What exactly does `$(function(toDemos) {...` do ?

Comment: Yes I use the Ariel Flersler scrollTo. So when #get-down is clicked, the window scrolls down to #content

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling the `html` element using the `scrollTop` method instead.

```
$('html').scrollTop(500);
```

or alternatively, if your #content is really scrollable, you can scroll that as well.

```
$('#content').scrollTop(500);
```

Comment: He is not using jQuery scrollTop method. He's using jQuery.ScrollTo plugin which has this method called scrollTo().

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know about this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It works, check this http://jsfiddle.net/8eve6/2/
Are you sure you have included some sort of jQuery plugin like this one here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js

```
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Yes I do, but my button(#geto-down) doesn't even react on 'cursor: pointer'. While it does react to the rest of the css

Comment: is it #get-down or #geto-down?

Comment: get-down. Just as it says in the html, css and js

Comment: Another issue that I can think of is z-index: -998; if it's being suppressed by some other element, you wont be able to even click on it. Try changing z-index to 1111 or figure out what's on top of it and get rid of the other element just for testing.

Comment: hm good point, but there seems to be nothing suppressing the element. It's just that the content will scroll over that part once you click it.

Comment: Found the cause but not the solution... It's because of some positioning of divs. I have an absolute div, which includes the #get-down. the div #content scrolls over that absolute div and is relative.

Comment: well, you need to post a different question for that then.